# where to place componentscan

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have spring mvc application with complete annotations. Where is the best place to add  @componentScan? Let me know any of these recommended

1. class that extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer?
2. class that extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport
3. class that extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

I placed in 2 without security and workign fine. When I added security, I got problem with security config not able to find userdetails service. Then I moved to 3.
I found  other issues with security and put code to just reuturn null instead of 
 securityconfig object from getRootConfigClasses(). Then I got issues of controllers not found. I am able to fix it to put componenentscan in 2.

I just want to know any links and  how it works. Is it ok to put @componentscan in all of these 3? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your project's package tree and what you want to scan. If you want to scan all annoted classes with such annotations like : `@Configuration, @Component, @Repository, etc...` put `@ComponentScan` at the top of your package tree.

You can also use the `basePackages` attribute to specify where to start the scanning.

Say you have an application packages organized like this :

`com.app.config`,`com.app.config.web`, `com.app.services`, `com.app.web.controllers`

If you want to scan all annoted classes, put the class annoted with `@ComponentScan` in `com.app` package.

If you want to scan only controller, add `@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.app.web.controllers")`

It's up to you to decide.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  Can I put dummy class MyClass in a package com.app  just with annotation @componentScan to scan everything? Or does it scan from main class like the class that implements  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer? I am trying to understand  how all beans are created without depending on security config object is returned or  null returned.

Comment: Yes you can, add also ˋ@Configuration` in that class, if you do so. All beans declared in com.app package and subpackages will be discovered. It's important to understand this point above all if your work one day with Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it. Right now  I put  @componentScan,  in both classes. So either object is created in any order, the beans are available without any problem

Comment: If it solved your problem accept the response for other users